# C# WUA IUpdate, Obtain MD5 Checksum before downloading Updates?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to obtain MD5 Checksum for a windows update file that has not been downloaded yet?

The reason for this is to somehow obtain that checksum, download the file from the link provided by Microsoft, then check against that hash to ensure the file is OK.

I was searching in: [IUpdate Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

But didn't find any particular property that will include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out , the Checksum is already included in the URI!

*For example:*

http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/software/crup/2012/10/windows8-rt-kb2768703-x64_**5c165f45d01373eb3aa01b85f387089fd1742acd**.cab

The bold part is the SHA1, In this case we can extract the checksum with the following:

```
string uri = "http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/software/crup/2012/10/windows8-rt-kb2768703-x64_5c165f45d01373eb3aa01b85f387089fd1742acd.cab";

string[] SHAtmp = uri.Split('_');
string[] SHA1SUM = SHAtmp[1].Split('.');

Console.Writeline(SHA1SUM[0]); //Provides the hash
```

Then if we wish to manually verify we can use a tool provided by Microsoft:
[File Checksum Integrity Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533)